# Vertical menu hover drop below with active state?

Tags: html, menu, hover

I need to create a vertical menu like so:

- Item 1

  - Item 1.1
  - Item 1.2
- Item 2
- Item 3
- Item 4

I need the sub-menu to expand/collapse **below** it's parent item on hover. I need it to have a page indicator or the ability to use the active state so the **menu displays the page you're currently on**. Also, this is going to be customized several times throughout a site, so I need to keep the titles/links in the html only.

I haven't been able to find or create a solution that fits all of these requirements. I have been researching for a few days and keep coming up empty handed. Any advice and/or solutions would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: create active_state class in your css and use javascript to add class active_state to <li>.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

May be a simple sliding jQuery menu would help you here.

[Here is an example fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/wUDQb/1/).

Let me know if it helps you or not.

**Edit**

Well for this *active-state* issue I had to play a little more with the code and finally I got it as you wanted it to be (i guess so)...

Here is the [**NEW FIDDLE**](http://jsfiddle.net/wUDQb/27/).

Also here now I am using `class selectors` that makes the code much smaller and easy to read... :)

Cheers..

**Update**:

May be this is what you want: http://jsfiddle.net/Zx2EU/3/

Comment: This is exactly what I needed! Thank you! Now I need to find a way to add the active_state functionality. Also, if I am able to add this functionality, will it be able to keep the "inner" element open without hover if it is active? Any help or tutorials for this would be much appreciated!

Comment: @MrsSecker have a look at updated code and let me know if anything troubles you..I did not write much as an answer because code is already very self explainatory..

Comment: @Mrs Secker if it's  exactly what you needed, it is the right answer and you should select it as the right answer.

Comment: @Asif - I had a hard time implementing your code. I talked to my client and they wanted to remove the animation (at first) so I came up with this Fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/Zx2EU/

However, now they would like the animation added back with an orange arrow to show when there is a submenu. Any advice on how to go about this with my current code? I'm new to CSS so it took me a while to get everything to look and function how I wanted.

Comment: I tried editing my code into yours - more appropriately using the IDs and classes. The hover animation is not working. At this point, I would settle for it expanding/collapsing on click. Again, not sure how to add this functionality to my current code. Here is my attempt to add your code: http://jsfiddle.net/Zx2EU/2/

Comment: @MrsSecker i don't know if i understand you exactly or not, but check out the UPDATEED FIDDLE as in the answer...hope it will help you..

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps something like the jQuery EasyUI "Async Tree", then just add some Javascript/PHP/whatever to determine if it is the current page or not, and then print something like < b > before every one (and < /b > at the end).

http://www.jeasyui.com/demo/index.php

For example:

```
<?php

$currentFile = $_SERVER["SCRIPT_NAME"];
$parts = Explode('/', $currentFile);
$currentFile = $parts[count($parts) - 1];

?>
...
<li<?php 
    if ($currentFile == "index.php") {
        echo " class=\"selected\"";
    } else {

    } 
    ?>>
    <a href="index.php">Homepage</a>
</li>
```

And in the stylesheet:

```
.selected { font-weight: bold; }
```

Dynamic Drive's might be a bit lighter: http://www.dynamicdrive.com/dynamicindex1/navigate1.htm

Also lookup Apycom, they might have one, but they aren't free.